# Python3.6.2　tkinterボタンを押してコマンドプロンプトにprintする方法

Tags: python, tkinter

Python3.6.2　と　windows10　の環境です。

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess


def func1():
    print("クリック")


def func2():
    subprocess.run(("start", "timeout", "/T", "10"), shell=True)


root = Tk()
Button(root, text="ボタン1", command=func1).pack()
Button(root, text="ボタン2", command=func2).pack()
mainloop()
```

起動する時は、拡張子pywでコンソール非表示です。
ボタン1をクリック時に、コマンドプロンプトが表示されてprintするようにするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか（func1は例なのですぐに消えてもかまいません）？
ボタン2のようにsubprocessで行ったようにしたいのですが。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

printの内容を確認するために標準出力を変更する方法は[本家SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3675815)に載っています。

***この回答はコンソールを表示する方法ではありません。***
あくまでも出力内容をコンソール以外で表示する対応方法ですので、ご注意ください。

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import sys

def func1():
    print("クリック")


def func2():
    subprocess.run(("start", "timeout", "/T", "10"), shell=True)

#追記モード(最新ログのみ表示したい場合は"a"→"w")
sys.stdout = open("mylog.txt", "a")
root = Tk()
Button(root, text="ボタン1", command=func1).pack()
Button(root, text="ボタン2", command=func2).pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: mylog.txtに書き込まれましたが、コマンドプロンプトが起動して表示されませんでした。
私の説明不足で申し訳ありません。
要は、コンソール非表示で起動したGUIのボタンを押して、コマンドプロンプトが起動して、そこに文字を表示したいのです。
func1関数は時間のかかる処理を想定していて、進捗状況などをprintしたいのです。そして処理が終わればコマンドプロンプトは消えてもらいます。
subprocess.run(("start", "python",～で、別のpyファイルを起動させたら、func2のようなことはできると思いますが、ファイルを分けるのも面倒なので、一つのプログラムで出来ないのかと思いまして質問しました。

Comment: 詳細な説明ありがとうございます。質問の意図を汲んだ上でコンソール表示とは異なる解決策を提示したつもりでしたが、分かりにくいようなので回答に説明を追記しました。